# Method takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, self

I am new to python and having trouble with the following code, I know it has something to do with the self keyword but I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

main code:

```
user_operation = UserOperations(headers)

user = user_operation.get_user(arguments['source'],arguments['id'])
```

user_operations:

```
class UserOperations(object):
    def __init__(self, headers):
        self.headers = headers

    def get_user(self, account_id, user_id):

        #Get user
        user = requests.get(api_root + "/accounts/" + account_id + "/users/" + user_id, headers=headers)

        #Throw exception if non-200 response
        user.raise_for_status()

        print "\nGet User " + user_id + ": " + user.text

        #Check user exists
        if user.json()['Data'] is None:
            return None

        #Return user
        return user.json()['Data']
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py-front.py", line 117, in <module>
    user = user_operation.get_user(arguments['<source>'],arguments['<id>'])
TypeError: get_user() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you subclass UserOperations from "headers"?

Comment: Oops, should it just be `object`?

Comment: sure it should be, unless you intend to subclass some other class which I don't think you are doing from the above code

Comment: does that solve your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I believe that error message came from that code.  For one thing, your error message doesn't match the line you say is calling it (`arguments['source'],arguments['id']` vs `arguments['<source>'],arguments['<id>']`).

Comment: @praveen, that did fix it, I was modifying one file and running another, derp. Thanks!